# Gaussian Distribution for Probability

Tags: probability, gaussian

Say I'm in a store, selling baubles. Each day, 100 people come to the store - each person has a 10% chance of buying a bauble. On average, 10 people will buy a bauble. But is there a gaussian distribution that models the chance of a given number of baubles being sold on each day? The mean would be 10, but would the standard deviation be? Is this an unsolvable problem?

Comment: [It's well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation). In particular, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Comment: I believe the Normal (Gaussian) approximation to the Binomial distribution is only valid when $p$ is near $1/2$. I don't think it works for $p=1/10$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it..

Comment: @QuaereVerum - The normal approx to binomial works for any $0 < p < 1$, as long as $n$ is _large enough_.  In practice, for highly skewed $p$ such as $1/10$, you just need a larger $n$, and I'm not sure $n=100$ is good enough.

Comment: Ok - thanks. I'll keep that in mind.